# Automocity in PHP (Begin and Commit in PHP)

Tags: php, transactions, commit

May be it sound silly, But i want to know that is there any way to enclose PHP codes in some functions so that if any error happen it rollback all process which it has done.? (like we done in mysql- Automocity) For ex :

```
$this->BEGIN;
$this->function1();
$this->function2();
$this->COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

A database server can simply rollback all changes to a database table, but since PHP is far more powerful, this cannot be done (easily).

You could do something like this:

```
try
{
    // Do something / create file
    file_put_contents("/tmp/test.txt", "Test");

    // ... some more actions here ...

    // some error occurs, rollback!
    if($some_error)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // undo all changes
    @unlink("/tmp/test.txt");
}
```

Also note that there are a few things that cannot be undone. A http call to some webservice for example.